# Ignore default field values for JSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I need to ignore field values in DTO during deserialization.

Example:

DTO calss

```
 public class Dto {
    
    private name = "test";
 }
```

Json

```
{}
```

The result of the deserialization is going to be an object with a name field that equals "test'.
I want on the contrary to get an empty object, where the name is null.

I was thinking to use all argument constructor with `@JsonCreator()`, but it's too wordy and I have to rewrite all parent classes

Comment: Did you try `@JsonProperty(defaultValue=null)`? Also, why do you have a default value in the first place, if you don't want to use it? Why just not have `private name;` and set the "default" value only in the cases where it's needed?

Comment: That is absaluty correct, I would not set those values, but others can do this.

Comment: @Thomas I just tried  @JsonProperty(defaultValue= null) does not help

Comment: Well, if others do that, there's probably a reason and that should be discussed with the developers. You could also use static code analysis to detect those situations and fail the build if you absolutely don't want this to happen.

Comment: You can always move default value to the getter method: `public String getName() {return name == null ? "test" : name;}`. You would have to implement custom deserialiser which in case of empty `JSON Object` would set `null` for name.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a @JsonSetter for that field

```java
 public class Dto {
    
    private name = "test";
    
    @JsonSetter("name") 
    public void nameJsonSetter(String value) {
        this.name = value != null ? value : "";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that setter not be called if there is no "name" field in the json?

Comment: @Thomas the setter is not going to be called. the Jackson create object by ValueInstantiator.createUsingDefault method, and then mapped the only field that presents in the JSON.